# Pseudo-nodes Vs line simplification

Tags: grass-gis, gis-principle

I am confused, whether  [removing pseudo-nodes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31589/find-pseudo-nodes-in-free-gis-software) and [line-simplification methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) should be considered as the same concept.

Line simplification is one normally done using Douglas-Peucker algorithm such as with v.generalize tool in GRASS.

Answer (score 2):

I would say they are not the same thing.

A pseudo node is a network "thing", a junction with a valency of two, i.e. 2 polylines connecting to a single point. So if you dissolved these two lines to remove the pseudo node then you get a single line that looks the same.

Line simplification, using the Douglas-Peucker algorithm alters the underlying geometry of a line by removing vertices from within the line to simplify the shape of it. My experience is you typically run this on a line by line basis.

So you could have a scenario where two lines are participating in a NETWORK, they connect at their end nodes to create a pseudo node (valency 2) and you could run a line simplification on these to simplify the line but this won't remove the junction, pseudo node. To do that you want to *dissolve* the lines.