# Delete Pseudo Nodes (or unncessary nodes) using PostGIS or QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, point, remove

I have so big big data (like about 60 Gb.) and it seems to have much unnecessary pseudo nodes.

I would like to remove them using PostGIS or QGIS without simplifying or changing its original shape 
(Simplification might helpful though it changes the original shape and this is not what I want... also, ArMap DataReviewer is not going to be helpful or GT Tools such as ArcMap Addin)

What function names should I look into?
I have polygons and polylines that need to be worked done.

[Finding pseudo nodes in free GIS software?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31589/find-pseudo-nodes-in-free-gis-software)

this might be the closest answer that i am looking for but this is related to lines and i need to delete them :(

examples of Pseudo Nodes in Polyline is illustrated below. (and the second picture, i need to apply this to polygons too)

[image]
[image]

an example of Pseudo Nodes in Polygon is illustrated below

[image]

so, the definition of Pseudo Nodes here is unnecessary nodes in a shape.
Also, with or without the pseudo nodes, the shape will still remain the same.

For instance, straight line only needs end nodes (2 nodes) but somehow there is a couple of extra nodes on the line (for some reason. maybe editting error), i would like to remove them.

Comment: Define what you mean with pseudo nodes. Degree of two vertices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory), or?

Comment: @user30184 sure sure i will edit my post

Comment: Did you try this old trick: buffer out by a very small amount, then buffer in by the same amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that what you call a pseudo-node is when there is two connected line where you only want a single line (the last vertice of the first line is superposed to the first vertice of the second line) if I understand well you want to mergedissolve some (or all) of the line to remove the duplicate vertice.

you may have a look at the "Merge lines", "Aggregate" or "Dissolve" tool to see if they fit your need

Comment: oh, dissolve is the function i should look into.

Comment: I guess without the shape loss (such as without simplification), this is the best solution I have found so far. Thank you for your help.